# At what point on the paraboloid $y = x^2 + z^2$ is the tangent plane parallel to the plane $x + 2y + 3z = 1$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tangent-spaces

I am not sure how to proceed.

This is what I think: I know that the gradient is perpendicular to the level curve of a function. does that mean that the gradient at a point will be parallel to the tangent plane at that exact point? If so, that would mean that the normal of the plane $x+2y+3z = 1$ is perpendicular to the gradient. and then from that, I just set the dot product of the gradient and the normal vector to 0 to find where it happens.
However, I highly doubt my approach and it made me realize that I don't really understand the geometric meaning of the gradient. Thus, can someone please how should i approach this problem intuitively.
[image]

Comment: $F=y-x^2-z^2$, $n=\langle1,2,3\rangle$. Gradient of $F$ must be a multiple of $n$. So, $\langle -2x,1,-2z \rangle=\langle 1,2,3\rangle k$ and $(x,y,z)=(-1/4,5/8,-3/4)$.

Comment: @BobDobbs how did you get F=y−x^2−z^2? Can you explain intuitively why you did that?

Comment: For a curve $y=f(x)$ we know that the slope is $f'(x)$. So tangent vector is $t=\langle 1, f'(x)\rangle$. On the other hand the gradient of $F=y-f(x)$:  is $n=\langle -f'(x), 1\rangle$. Now,  $t\cdot n=0$. They are perpendicular. We have to mimic this for surfaces.

Comment: The tangent plane to $F=-x^2+y-z^2=0$ at a point $P(a,b,c)$ on the surface, intuitively, is the linear term (the constant term vanishes) of $k(-(x+a)^2+(y+b)-(z+c)^2),$ in which the point $P$ is translated to the origin. Now $k=2$ since we have the coefficient of $y.$ So $a$ must be $-1/4$ and similarly $c$ must be $-3/4$ by comparing coefficients. Then adjust $b$ to $5/8$ so the point is on the surface, making $P(-1/4,5/8,-3/4).$ The actual tangent plane is found from $x+2y+3z=0$ by translating back: $(x+1/4)+2(y-5/8)+3(x+3/4)=0$ or $x+2y+3z=-3/8.$ This generalizes; google tangent cone.